# Reduce database calls with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-performance

Would it be possible to write this in 1 statement (make only 1 db call?) and still be able to differentiate between "The member did not exist" and "The member did exist but had no dogs".

```
public IEnumerable<Dog> GetDogsOfMember(int id)
{
    if (dbContext.Members.Any(i => i.ID == id))
    {
        return dbContext.Dogs.Where(i => i.Member.ID == id);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: by default, if your .Where doesn't have a result, it will cause you "no error" and just return null after search. so even without checking, you can code this as public IEnumerable<Dog> GetDogsOfMember(int id)
{ return dbContext.Dogs.Where(i => i.Member.ID == id); }

Comment: you use the caching to restrict the db calls

Comment: True, but I'd like to be able to differentiate between "if the member did not exist" or "if the member had no dogs". I guess I could use that though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each `Dog` already contains a reference to the `Member`, you can expose the other end of the relationship (if you didn't already):

```
public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can issue a single efficient query using `Include()`:

```
public IEnumerable<Dog> GetDogsOfMember(int id)
{
    var memberWithDogs = dbContext.Members
                                  .Include(i => i.Dogs)
                                  .SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == id);

    if (memberWithDogs != null)
        return memberWithDogs.Dogs;

    return null;
}
```